# Installing router - failed to verify router settings

Tags: router

I'm trying to install a TP-Link wireless router. I am using a modem an have a PPPoE connection. I connected the router to the computer and the modem, but in the last step of the Easy Setup it says " Failed to verify router settings. 1. Please check the WAN connection type and parameters. 2. Please check your connectivity and retry."

The internet works fine if i connect the modem directly to the computer. 
When I connect the computer to the router, the wireless network is detected by other devices, but cannot be accessed.

I accessed the router settings, and everything seems normal, except that it just says "Connecting...". It never manages to connect to the internet. I tried restarting the router and several walkthroughs on the web, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: There is usually a page in the router config for you to enter in your PPPoE settings, ie username and password so if you don't have those handy call your ISP to obtain them.

Comment: PPPoE is only necessary on one device. If the modem is authenticating, then the router simply needs to accept an IP from the modem. What WAN settings are you using on the router?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.. the mistake I was making was that I was selecting PPPoE settings whereas I should have selected **Dynamic IP** because I havent been given a user id or password by my service provider. In dynamic IP option it automatically detects the given IP by the provider. My router is now connected flawlessly :) no more error of "failed to verify router settings"